# ClickHouse , Issue with select top n and order by primary key

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table with 3 billion rows, when i do query like this

```
Select * from tsnew where time > 971128806382 and time <971172006000
limit 100
```

Its working fine and it takes 0.2 seconds
But when adding order to the query to be like this:

```
Select * from tsnew where time > 971128806382 and time <971172006000
order by time desc
limit 100
```

it takes very long time (more than 20 seconds).

```
create table tsnew(
ext_rec_num Nullable(UInt64),
xdr_id Nullable(UInt64),
xdr_grp Nullable(UInt64),
xdr_type Nullable(UInt64),
xdr_subtype Nullable(Int16),
xdr_direction Nullable(Int16),
xdr_location Nullable(Int16),
time UInt64,
stop_time UInt64,
transaction_duration Nullable(UInt64),
response_time Nullable(UInt64),
protocol Nullable(Int16),
chunk_count Nullable(Int16),
dpc Nullable(Int32), 
opc Nullable(Int32), 
first_link_id String,
last_dpc Nullable(Int32),
last_opc Nullable(Int32),
last_link_id String,
first_back_opc Nullable(Int32),
first_back_link_id String,
calling_ssn Nullable(Int16),
called_ssn Nullable(Int16),
called_sccp_address String,
calling_party_address String,
response_calling_address String,
root_end_code Nullable(Int32),
root_cause_code Nullable(Int32),
root_cause_pl Nullable(Int16),
root_failure Nullable(Int16),
root_equip Nullable(Int16)
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toInt64(time/3600000)*3600000 
order by time
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: could you provide the table definition (*CREATE TABLE*-query)?

Comment: I updated the question with the table definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's known [issue](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/1344). Hope it will be merged [asap](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/1344#issuecomment-506988614). Subscribe to the PR and upgrade your CH when PR will be merged.

Comment: Thanks slesh, Can you please guide me how i can upgrade my CH to use the fix in this PR, I installed CH from this command sudo apt-get install -y clickhouse-server clickhouse-client

Comment: It depends on your system. The latest version of CH should be available in package repository you system uses, make sure that you have yandex package repository in sourcelist(please, check this [guid](https://clickhouse.yandex/#quick-start)). As alternative way you can [build](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/development/build/) the latest CH from source

Comment: I did the build step, but I already installed it before, now I have 2 instances ? If yes ,then how i can run the last one (the one i built it) ?

Comment: No, you'll have single one. To be one hundred percents sure, you can uninstall previous CH, and install a new one.